# How can i omit the redundant words in python condition loop

Tags: python, loops

I am using this function

```
    obj = myotherobj if obj is None else obj
```

I see that word `obj` is used three times. Is there any way to write that function with obj appearing only once

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with the extra letters?

Comment: Gotta be a Picky Pythonista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Getting it down to 1 instance of the token `obj` is tough, but there are plenty of fun ways to reduce it to 2 instances.

Depending on the [truthiness](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/2005120/implicit-boolean-evaluation-aka-truthinessfalsiness) of `obj` you can do this:

```
obj = obj or myotherobj
```

For example:

```
>>> obj = []
>>> obj = obj or 9000
>>> obj
9000
>>> obj = None
>>> obj = obj or True
>>> obj
True
```

Alternatively, you can cut this to one `obj` if its part of a return statement:

```
return obj or otherobj
```

For example:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...  return x or 8
...
>>> foo(4)
4
>>> foo([])
8
>>> foo(0)
8
```

And for extra fun, if this is a [code-golfing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf), you can do some cool things with array indexing and booleans (but this won't cut down your number of `obj` tokens):

```
>>> obj=None
>>> obj=[obj,9000][obj is None]  
>>> obj
9000
```

And just for fun, the ultra ridiculous:

```
>>> obj = None
>>> obj = (obj,[1,2,3])[::cmp(bool(obj),0.5)]
>>> obj
[1, 2, 3]
>>> obj = True
>>> obj = (obj,[1,2,3])[::cmp(bool(obj),0.5)]
>>> obj
True
```

But neither of the above are usually recommended for any sane production code.

Comment: You can also do `obj = [obj,9000][not obj]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if obj is None:
    obj = myotherobj
```

As there's no null-coalescing operator in Python, 2 occurrences is probably the best you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut it down to two:

```
if obj is None:
    obj = myotherobj
```

Note you don't need to assign `obj` to anything if it isn't None, since in your example `obj` is apparently already set to what you want it to be in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be

```
obj = myotherobj if not obj else obj
```

As in python **None** itself implies **False** there is no need to check *"if obj is None"*.